# How can I get a substring from a XML Element by xPath?

Tags: xml, xpath

Source XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ServerAnswer>
  <Booking Data="AABB150908"/>
  <Booking Data="AABB150907"/>
</ServerAnswer>
```

My XPath:

```
//Booking/@Data[substring(//Booking/@Data,4,6)]
```

If I Query that xPath by http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath I only get the complete Data. How can I only get the given Date in Data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xpath counts from 1, not from 0

```
substring(//Booking/@Data,5,6)
```